set line join in tikz globally
I want to set line join to be round globally.
But using \tikzset{line join=round} in preamble does not work.
I find that line join is said to be "(no default, initially miter)" in pgfmanual.pdf 15.3.1.
But, line join/.initial=round does not work, neither.
The following is the MWE.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{line join/.initial=round}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path(0,0)rectangle(2.5,1);
  \draw[line join=round](0,0)--(2,.5)--(0,1);
  \draw(0,0)--(1.8,.5)--(0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

As you can see, setting line join=round locally works, but setting it globally does not.
Could you provide some suggestions?

You could use every path/.style like this
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{every path/.style={line join=round}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line join=round] (0,0) -- (2,.5) -- (0,1);
\draw (0,0) -- (1.8,.5) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



every picture/.style={line join=round} also works!
